# uwsgi django at boot fail to start without postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, uwsgi

Debian server, uwsgi at boot started by a crontab @reboot.

return this in **uwsgi.log**:

> ile
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py",
>   line 175, in get_new_connection
>       connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py", line 164, in
>   connect
>       conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async) django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to
>   server: Connection refused    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1"
>   and accepting     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>
> Thu Mar 24 05:19:02 2016 - unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='')
>   (callable not found or import error) Thu Mar 24 05:19:02 2016 - *** no
>   app loaded. going in full dynamic mode**  Thu Mar 24 05:19:02 2016 -
>    **uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***

if I wait that also postgresql start and restart uwsgi all is working.

Are there way to tell uwsgi to wait for postgresql?

Comment: What version of Debian are you using?

Comment: @GwynBleidD I'm using Debian stretch/sid, inux server 4.3.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.3.3-2 (2015-12-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux , with postgresql 9.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use systemd to start uWSGI instead of cron daily.

Create file `/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service` with content:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI
After=syslog.target
After=postgresql@9.4-main.service
Wants=postgresql@9.4-main.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGTERM
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Change of course start command for anything you want.

If you want to start more than one uWSGI server (for more than one user perhaps), consider using [uWSGI Emperor](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Emperor.html). You can even create some shared directory in which everyone can create and manage it's own files (by setting sticky bit on directory) and set emperor in tyrant mode, so every vassal will start only from user account that owns specified file, if you want to give anyone ability to create own uWSGI instances.